# ownership property of binary semaphore

Tags: c, linux, ipc, linux-device-driver, archlinux

Can some one help me to understand the ownership property of binary semaphore in linux ?

```
thread1:                        
acquire(lock)                     
do some work                     

thread2:

do some work

release(lock)
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/11/23/496248.aspx. - "semaphores don't have owners"

Comment: Yes Exactly , I want to prove the same with some samples may be implementing wait mechanism some like below                                                 readThread ()
{
      sem_wait(SEM1);
      //wait for reading here

}

writeThread ()
{

    //Write something here
    sem_post(SEM1);

}                                                                                                                  Note: Here SEM1 is a global/common semaphore for both reader and writer threads